# Angular: check if a component is part of the routing

Tags: angular, routes

I want know if one of my child is loaded into the active route so i can show or hide specific element from the parent component.

Comment: That sounds nice, do you have a question? :)

Comment: Yes sure : do you know when one of my child component is loaded into the active route?